# How to call a C# method from inside Regex.Replace?

Tags: c#, regex

I want to be able to send a string like this:

> This is the *first* and the *second* word.

and get back a string like this:

> This is the _______ (stfri) and the ______ (cnodes) word.

But the following code doesn't work since inside `Regex.Replace` it simply sends `$0` once, gets `$0` back and then uses it as a variable to display the appropriate word, i.e. it returns

> This is the ________ (*first*) and the ________ (*second*) word.

**How can I get inside the Regex loop and call my `ScrambleWord` function on each iteration?**

```
class Program
    {

        public static Random TheRandom;


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TheRandom = new Random();

            string text = "This is the *first* and the *second* word.";
            string message = Regex.Replace(text, @"\*[a-z]+\*", @"________ (" + ScrambleWord("$0") + ")");

            Console.WriteLine(message);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static string ScrambleWord(string word)
        {
            string r = word;
            r = r.Replace("*", "");
            r = ShuffleLetters(r);
            return r;
        }

        public static string ShuffleLetters(string str)
        {
            char[] array = str.ToCharArray();
            int n = array.Length;
            while (n > 1)
            {
                n--;
                int k = TheRandom.Next(n + 1);
                var value = array[k];
                array[k] = array[n];
                array[n] = value;
            }
            return new string(array);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, there's the overload of [`Regex.Replace` that accepts a callback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @Amy, that was a very useful tip and link, thanks, this works perfectly: `string message = Regex.Replace(text, @"\*[a-z]+\*", m => @"________ (" + ScrambleWord(m.Value) + ")");`